# How to prevent ctrl+f5 or f5 to current page in jquery not the whole application?

Tags: jquery, ajax, page-refresh

I have codeigniter application using jquery ajax,It having 4 menus(user,about us,carriers,contact us).when i am in carriers page if i press ctrl+f5 whole application getting refreshed instead have to load the particular page only.How to i achieve this usinbg jquery.Some one help me out.

Comment: why do you want to prevent f5 and shift+f5, what about the refresh button?

Comment: you need to save the state of your application in storage for you to retrieve it after the page refresh

Comment: refresh button or anything ,when a user clicks ctrl+f5 on a specific page it reloads whole application i want for that page alone

Comment: i think you have a single page and you load some page content via ajax, f5/refresh will refresh the whole page, i don't think is possible to directly refresh only a part of the page